# Mouse pointer dissappears after Login...?

Tags: 13.10, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 where in the problem arises that whenever i log into my account the mouse pointer disappears and i have to logout and again login so anyone can state the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I only encounter this the first login after a fresh install, but not after that. Does this occur consistently for you?

Also is your home partition encrypted?

Comment: yeah it encounters consistently and my home partition is not encrypted

Comment: Today I had no mouse, not just no pointer (before I could still aimlessly click on things). I opened up Unity HUD and opened up firefox with the keyboard. As soon as the firefox window appeared, the mouse appeared.

Comment: for me it doesnt happen still yet